# Can't buy anything from Store or Global Items because of strange bug

Tags: technical-issues, dota-2, steam-community-market

Whenever I try to buy something my cursor changes from the styled one in Dota 2 to the normal one from Windows and if I move it around I see it change to *select text*, so **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>** [gives this output. [pastebin link]](http://pastebin.com/8gHaV4KQ)

Basically the Steam popup/window is invisible. I tried reinstalling Dota 2 but this didn't fix it.

[image: screenshot of mouse cursor changing]

Answer (score 1):

Try relaunching Dota 2 from the Big Picture Client. The result is that a different Steam layout appears whenever you Shift-Tab. See if you are now able to purchase.

Comment: Didn't work. Also shift-tab has the same behaviour as clicking the market button.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I think there is a problem with Steam Overlay. I also face the same problem only the client browser won't load at _all_. The same problem doesn't happen in another computer. Tried reinstalling Steam afresh?